# Computing arc elasticity for categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, elasticity, multinomial-logit

I want to compute arc elasticity for a categorical variable that has more than 2 categories. In fact, I have estimated a multinomial logit model of mode choice and have included street type as a categorical variable with 5 categories. I have read in a reference that we can calculate the incremental change in each probability with respect to a category shift and to use the differences to compute arc elasticity.

I would like to ask if it's correct that for computing the elasticity of each street type (the 3 categories that showed significant effect on mode choice) we simulate the model for a scenario where all the respondents (about 600 respondents) live in that street type and then use the simulated probability of choosing a mode as P2 and the simulated probability of choosing that mode before this shift as P1, and the number of people living in that street type before the shift as X1 and the number of people living in that street type after the shift (all respondents) as X2 to calculate arc elasticity using the common formula for mid point or acr elasticity: p2-p1/p2+p1(1/2)/x2-x1/x2+x1(1/2) ? Does that make sense?

I'm also wondering if it is more meaningful if we do not include the respondents living in the reference street type (the one that was held outside the model as the reference) for the shift?

Also, I saw in another article that elasticity for a categorical variable (having two categories of conventional neighborhoods and new urbanist neighborhoods) was computed as proportional increase of probability of a mode for one category relative to another category. However, there was no explanation on how this proportional increase (or ratio) has been calculated. I mean whether they have calculated this elasticity for example for new urbanist neighborhood for the assumption that all respondents move to a new urbanist neighborhood. And, then how the relative proportional increase was computed.

I have read some comments on this blog that elasticity is meaningless for categorical variables but since I have seen the above mentioned references I wonder if arc elasticity (or elasticity) can be computed for categorical variables.

I would be grateful if anyone could guide me on this and let me know your idea about whether the first procedure I mentioned is correct for computing arc elasticity for a categorical variable.